# How to replace PDF.js in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, pdf.js

I'm using `AngularJS`, `jQuery` and `Bootstrap`, all latest versions.

When showing a `PDF` embedded inside a page, the js makes use of `PDF.js v1.1.366`

Question: How can I override/replace the version used, and instead make use of the most recent version of `PDF.js`?

Comment: Which library are you using to add PDF to a page? I guess pdf.js is loaded from CDN?

Comment: I'm just embedding the pdf using `<iframe ng-src="path.to.pdf" />`. The PDF.js is somehow loaded automatically, I guess by angular or jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach with iframe is browser depended and if it would be me doing this, I wouldn't trust it in production.

You can use 3rd party library and handle pdf embedding yourself:

https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/ or angular wrapper https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf

Comment: whether  https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf supports multiple pdf in same page tried unable to achive.Have any idea on that.